# Just passing through: Estimating the probability that a changing quantity will pass through some value within a time interval?

Tags: confidence-interval, conditional-probability, measurement, random-walk

Suppose I have a quantity that is measured periodically, that is continuous in the following sense: In order for the quantity x to move from x=a to x=b, x must pass through all the values between a and b, though these intermediate values may occur between measurements. Let the measurements of x follow a known distriburion which, like the normal, is fully determined by the mean and standard deviation. We have values of them estimated from a recent sample.

Given that I have the value of x at time t, are the facts above sufficient to determine the probability (p) that x will pass through a specific value x* by t+n, where n is measured in the same units as the sampling frequency? If so, how? Does this answer change if the known distribution is of the changes in x, the first difference, rather than in x itself?

Comment: The answer is a clear negative, because you haven't described recording the *time* of any measurement.  The univariate empirical distribution of the measurements tells you relatively little.  If you do have these data recorded as an irregular time series, then you still need a more restrictive set of model assumptions to make much progress, because continuous motions isn't a sufficient restriction.  Moreover, if the choice of measurement times is at all related to the previous observations, that will be crucial information.

Comment: @andrewH  It might potentially be fruitful to look at level-crossings of stochastic processes to see if your issue can be formulated to fit that framework